# Create multiple instances of an object c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement something to instantiate an object multiple times. The following code is to create an html listener and want them to be alive till the end of the process. So basically I don't want to write down 10 times rather find a way to automatically create it 10 times.

I tried this but the listeners don't seem to be running.

```
public static void MultipleProxy()
{
    var proxies = new List<SocksWebProxy>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        proxies.Add(Proxy(i));
    }
}

public static SocksWebProxy Proxy(int i)
{
    var proxy = new SocksWebProxy(new ProxyConfig(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7000 + i, IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9000 + i, ProxyConfig.SocksVersion.Five));
    return proxy;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "start an object"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already creating 10 instances of SocksWebProxy. The problem with this code is that the objects go out of scope just as soon as the method to create them all exits, leaving them eligible for garbage collection. To solve that problem, you can move the List e.g. to class scope.

```
private static List<SocksWebProxy> proxies = new List<SocksWebProxy>();

public static void MultipleProxy()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        proxies.Add(Proxy(i));
    }
}
```

Multiple calls to MultipleProxy() would keep adding to the list with this design.

Comment: Oh I see I almost got it right! :) Thanks Eric

Comment: Yep. It's the right idea. You just need to understand that objects without anything referencing them can go away at any time (garbage collection).

Answer (score 3):

You are creating the objects and putting them on a list, but the list is stored on a local variable. After the method ends, the list is destroyed, and the objects are destroyed too by the garbage collector. Store them in a variable that lives the whole time.

Comment: Thanks Cecilio yours is good answer too but I can only accept one